# Class that can be used instead of Ext.grid.RowModel in Ext.js version 7

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, upgrade

I want to edit a script that is written in Ext.js 3.4
There is a ext function Ext.grid.RowSelection. I want to know which funtion in used in ext.s version 7.5 intead of the above funtion

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I guess you are looking for: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.0/classic/Ext.selection.RowModel.html